# How to determine whether $\Bbb P ( B_{t_1} \in [x - c , x + c ], \ldots , B_{t_n} \in [x -c , x + c ])$ is decreasing in $x$?

Tags: probability, integration, derivatives, normal-distribution

Let $\phi_t (z) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{-\frac {z^2} {2t}}$. By intuition $\omega : [0,\infty ) \to [0,1]$
\begin{align}
\omega (x) &:= \Bbb P ( B_{t_1} \in [x - c , x + c ], \ldots , B_{t_n} \in [x -c , x + c ])\\ &=\int_{x-c}^{x+c} \phi_{t_1} (y_1) \int_{x-c}^{x+c} \phi_{t_2-t_1} (y_2 - y_1) \ldots \int_{x-c}^{x+c} \phi_{t_n -t_{n-1}} (y_n - y_{n-1}) \text d y_n \ldots\text d y_1
\end{align}
should be decreasing in $x$. For $n=1$ this is easily done by derivating in $x$. Does anyone see a better way for this case here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=1$, the expression

$$\omega (x) = \int_{x-c}^{x+c} \phi_{t_1} (y)= \int_{-c}^c \phi_{t_1} (y+x)\text d y$$

is decreasing in $x\in[0,\infty)$, since $\phi_t\colon\Bbb R\to(0,\infty)$ is symmetric around the origin and strictly decreasing (increasing) on the positive (negative) half-axis. This is essentially the same reason why the argument with taking the derivative works, too.

For $n>1$, we might use induction. We have

\begin{align}
\omega (x) &= \int_{-c}^c \phi_{t_1} (y_1+x) \int_{-c}^{c} \phi_{t_2-t_1} (y_2 - y_1) \ldots \int_{-c}^{c} \phi_{t_n -t_{n-1}} (y_n - y_{n-1}) \text d y_n \ldots\text d y_1 \\
&= \int_{-c}^c \phi_{t_1} (y_1+x) g(y_1) \text d y_1,
\end{align}

where **both** $g\colon\Bbb R\to(0,\infty)$ **and** $\phi_t\colon\Bbb R\to(0,\infty)$ are symmetric around the origin and strictly decreasing (increasing) on the positive (negative) half-axis.

Note that $\omega$ may be defined in the same way for negative $x$ as well, and that the resulting function will be decreasing in $|x|$.

Comment: I think I got it by an induction over $n$. Didn't you provide an approach by induction yesterday, too?

Comment: Yes, but then I had doubts due to some downvote, but I had no time to rethink it. I just rolled back to that version, in case you want to compare your argument with my approach.

Comment: I guess I can believe your claims for $g$ and $\phi_{t_{1}}$ (though I see no proof) but I don't know how you get from there to the conclusion. And if there's induction in there I don't see it.

Comment: I posted my induction. I have to admit that I don't see a direct argument in your approach neither.

Comment: Let
$  g_{k+1}(x)
  =\int_{-c}^{c}\phi_{\tau_{k}}(x+y)g_{k}(-y)\mathrm{d}y $
where
$ \tau_{k}=t_{n-k+1}-t_{n-k} $. Then
$  g_{k+1}(-x)=\int_{-c}^{c}\phi_{\tau_{k}}(x+y)g_{k}(y)\mathrm{d}y $
so $g_{k}$ even implies $g_{k+1}$ even.
By induction $g_{k}$ even for all $k$.
Now $  g_{k+1}'(x)=\left(\phi_{\tau_{k}}(x+c)-\phi_{\tau_{k}}(x-c)\right)g_{k}(c)$
  $-  \int_{0}^{c}
  \left(\phi_{\tau_{k}}(x+u)-\phi_{\tau_{k}}(x-u)\right)g'_{k}(u)\,\mathrm{d}u $
  so $g_{k}$ decreasing on $(0,\infty)$ implies the same for $g_{k+1}$. By induction $g_{k}$ decreasing on $(0,\infty)$ for all $k$.

Comment: Mars Plastic's argument works just fine then :) I will change my downvote to an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\PRx}[2]{\Bbb{P}_{#1} (#2)}$

Let $c>0$ and $G\subset (0,\infty)$ a finite set of time points. The function $\omega : \Bbb R \to [0,1]$ given by $\omega (x) := \Bbb P_x ({\vert{B_s}\vert \leq c\ \forall s \in G})$ is radial nonincreasing.

The strategy is induction over $\vert G \vert$. For $\vert G \vert =1$ the derivative of $\omega (x)$ is $\phi_t (x+c) - \phi_t (x-c) \leq 0$. Let $G$ be arbitrary, $s = \min G$ and write $\tilde{G} := \{t-s : t \in G\setminus \{s\} \}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\omega (x) = \int_{-c}^c \phi_s (y-x) \Bbb P_y ({\vert{B_r}\vert\leq c \ \forall r\in \tilde{G}}) \text d y = \int_{-c}^c \phi_s (y-x) \tilde{\omega} (y) \text d  y
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{\omega}(y) := \PRx{y}{\vert{B_r}\vert\leq c \ \forall r\in \tilde{G}}$ is radial nonincreasing by assumption. Let $x\geq 0 $. Then by differentiation of parameter integrals
\begin{align*}
\omega ' (x) &=  \int_{-c}^c \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi_s (y-x) \tilde{\omega} (y) \text d  y =  \int_{-c}^c  \frac{y-x}{s} \phi_s (y-x) \tilde{\omega} (y) \text d  y\\
&= \int_{-c-x}^{c-x} \frac{y}{s} \phi_s (y) \tilde{\omega} (y+x) \text d  y 
\end{align*}
which is clearly non-positive if $x\geq c$. In the other case rewrite above as
\begin{align*}
&\int_0^{c-x} \frac{y}{s} \phi_s (y) \tilde{\omega} (y+x) \text d  y + \int_{-c-x}^0 \frac{y}{s} \phi_s (y) \tilde{\omega} (y+x) \text d  y\\
&=  \int_0^{c-x} \frac{y}{s} \phi_s (y) \tilde{\omega} (x+y) \text d  y - \int_0^{c+x} \frac{y}{s} \phi_s (y) \tilde{\omega} (x -y) \text d  y\\
&=  \int_0^{c-x} \frac{y}{s} \phi_s (y) \tilde{\omega} (x +y) \text d  y - \int_0^{c-x} \frac{y}{s} \phi_s (y) \tilde{\omega} (x -y) \text d  y -\int_{c-x}^{c+x} \frac{y}{s} \phi_s (y) \tilde{\omega} (x -y) \text d  y\\
&=  \int_0^{c-x} \frac{y}{s} \phi_s (y) ( \tilde{\omega} (x +y) - \tilde{\omega} (x -y) )\text d  y -\int_{c-x}^{c+x} \frac{y}{s} \phi_s (y) \tilde{\omega} (x -y) \text d  y\\
&\leq 0
\end{align*}
since $\tilde{\omega} (x +y) - \tilde{\omega} (x -y) \leq 0$ due to the fact that $\vert{x-y}\vert \leq \vert{x+y}\vert$. Therefore the assertion follows by induction.